# Python - multiprocessing using safe add function

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os
class Cal:
    def add( self, num):
        added = num + 3
        time.sleep(3)
        print( str(os.getppid()) + " // " + str( num) + " -> " + str( added))
        return added
class Worker:
    def __init__( self, cal):
        self.cal = cal
    def run( self, param):
        return cal.add( param)

cal = Cal()
def fun( num):
    return Worker( cal).run( num)

cpuCount = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
with Pool( cpuCount) as p:
    print( p.map(fun, range(50)))
```

I made code that add 3 to each number and return them in multi processing. It seems to work well, but I curious that Cal.add function is used in proper way. the cal class instance was created at once (checked by pid). is there any way to use same memory in other thread which is created by Pool?

Comment: No, don't do that. Python has GIL preventing more than one core to access same memory, which avoid memory leakage. Multiprocessing is purposed to use multiple cores to perform multiple INDEPENDENT tasks, still obeying the GIL.

Comment: The cal instance is only created once but through fork it is duplicated for each worker.

Comment: What if I create Cal instance in Work Class for each work instance like this 'return Cal().add( param)'. is that still unsafe?